# changing setting from cookie to selectable

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm displaying data with the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table 
          WHERE 
          city LIKE '$city' 
          AND approved = '1' 
          AND enddate > NOW() 
          ORDER BY id DESC";
```

City is defined as :

```
    $city=str_replace(array('-','\'','"'), array(' ','',''), trim($_GET['city']));
```

and that works great, but now when a user logs in, their local city is stored in a different table, I dont want to keep making queries to multiple tables so i'm carrying it with a $_SESSION from the login page.

My question is this, when you first login the DB query should be based on user settings which are:

```
$city=str_replace(array('-','\'','"'), array(' ','',''), trim($_SESSION['user_city']));
```

and that works great as well, only problem is when you try to change the city on the site, it keeps sticking to the cookie.

How would I set it that only on login `$city = cookie,` and after its clicked,

```
city = $_GET['blah'] ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an utterly horrible SQL escaping function, and WILL bite you in the rump at some point. Do not roll your own escaping function - use the one that's provided for you: `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have obtained the city using below

```
$city=str_replace(array('-','\'','"'), array(' ','',''), trim($_SESSION['user_city']));
```

why don't you just unset $_SESSION['user_city']. That way $_SESSION['user_city'] will not persist and you can assign $city any other value you like later.

```
<?php unset($_SESSION['user_city']); ?>
```